# Monitor subordinates computers

Tags: networking, monitoring

I need to monitor my subordinate's computer with their permission. Can you suggest some softwares for this ?

There may be one client application installed on n number of PCs and one server program which is to be installed on my computer.

Comment: Depends on what you want to monitor. Is that some software usage and website visits etc?

Comment: *Can you suggest some softwares for this?* isn't a constructive question, sorry. Per our [FAQ], polling for opinion and extended lists of answers isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zabbix and nagios are good tools -if you intend to monitor parameters like CPU, Memory and disk space usage etc.